# Incorrect Parsing of dates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hello I am trying to change my dataframe dates into a format i can use to extract useful information.
The dataset comes with a **'week'** feature that is in the form DD/MM/YY as follows:

```
In [128]: df_train[['week', 'units_sold']]
Out[128]: 
            week  units_sold
0       17/01/11          20
1       17/01/11          28
2       17/01/11          19
3       17/01/11          44
4       17/01/11          52
```

I have changed the dates as follows:

```
df_train['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['week'])

        new_date  units_sold
0     2011-01-17        20.0
1     2011-01-17        28.0
2     2011-01-17        19.0
3     2011-01-17        44.0
4     2011-01-17        52.0
```

Using the 'new_date' feature I created, I did the following for some information extraction:

```
df_train['weekday'] = df_train['new_date'].dt.weekofyear             #week day of the year
df_train['QTR'] = df_train['new_date'].apply(lambda x: x.quarter)    #current quarter of the year
df_train['month'] = df_train['new_date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)    #current month
df_train['year'] = df_train['new_date'].dt.year                      #current year
```

However, when reviewing my data I run into some errors. For example a certain date in my dataset is 07/02/11 which should translate to a month of 2. except my parsing shows that the month is 7, which I know is incorrect: **see entry 3483**

```
Out[127]: 
          week  month
18    17/01/11      1
1173  24/01/11      1
2328  31/01/11      1
3483  07/02/11      7
4638  14/02/11      2
```

Can anyone tell me where i went wrong?
Any help is apprecaited!

Answer (score 2):

Use `dayfirst=True` parameter:

```
df_train['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['week'], dayfirst=True)
```

And then [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html?highlight=dt#pandas.Series.dt) accessor for improve performance, because in apply are loops under the hood:

```
df_train['weekday'] = df_train['new_date'].dt.weekofyear #week day of the year
df_train['QTR'] = df_train['new_date'].dt.quarter    #current quarter of the year
df_train['month'] = df_train['new_date'].dt.month    #current month
df_train['year'] = df_train['new_date'].dt.year
```